# Filter rows from a table read by \pgfplotstableread

Tags: pgfplots

As everyone knows from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98003/filter-rows-from-a-table/98016#98016), it is possible to filter rows from a table using `discard if not` style/filter. But this solution works only if one provides a filename as the argument to `\addplot table`, and it won't work if one read the table using `\pgfplotstableread{file}\name` and use it as the argument `\addplot[discard if not...] table \name;`:

[image: no]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{fulltable.dat}
houses  instance    value
20      1           8919
20      2           8965
20      3           8901
20      4           8816
20      5           8875
20      6           9027
20      7           8915
20      8           8907
20      9           8832
20      10          8934
200     1           84714
200     3           85630
200     4           84748
200     5           84565
200     6           85109
200     7           84588
200     8           84638
200     9           84673
200     10          85170
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \edef\tempa{\thisrow{#1}}
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifx\tempa\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{fulltable.dat}\fulltable

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[
      title={{\bfseries Plot for 20 houses instances}},
      xlabel={Instance},
      ylabel={Value}]
    \addplot+[only marks, discard if not={houses}{20}] table[x=instance, y=value]
      {fulltable.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[
      title={{\bfseries Plot for 20 houses instances}},
      xlabel={Instance},
      ylabel={Value}]
    \addplot+[only marks, discard if not={houses}{20}] table[x=instance, y=value]
      {\fulltable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What to do? I want this thing working for macros.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. I guess than you have to *fix* the already reported [bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/109/) or *wait* until it will be fixed by somebody else ...

Answer (score 7):

## tl;dr

The following work

```
\def\thisrowunavailableloadtabledirectly{thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly}
\def\sudogetthisrow#1#2{
    \edef#2{\thisrow{#1}}
    \ifx#2\thisrowunavailableloadtabledirectly % if \thisrow fails to get the element
                            % then #2 is thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directlye
                            % we have a backup
        \getthisrow{#1}{}
        \let#2=\pgfplotsretval
    \fi
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \sudogetthisrow{#1}\tempa
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifnum\tempa=\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
            \message{^^J\tempa,\tempb,\pgfmathresult^^J}
        }
    }
}
```

## Story

When reading the table from a macro, pgfplots will execute the macro `\pgfplots@addplotimpl@table@fromstructure@`. In this situation `\thisrow` and `\thisrowno` do not work. Therefore in `pgfplotscoordprocessing.code.tex` line 6522-6529 the author added some comment

> ```
> % These macros are-unfortunately- not accessable here. And the
> % worst is: error messages are impossible either because they are
> % not executed... try to provide useful hints:
> \def\thisrow##1{thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly}%
> \def\thisrowno##1{thisrowno_unavailable_load_table_directly}%
> % this should work.
> \def\getthisrow##1##2{\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{##1}\of{#3}{##2}}%
> \def\getthisrowno##1##2{\pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{[index]##1}\of{#3}{##2}}%
> %
> ```

It seems like the author suggests that we should use `\getthisrow{houses}\tempa` instead.

However if you try it, you will get another error. The reason is that `\pgfplotstablegetelem` takes only three arguments. So `{##2}` (which will be `\tempa`) will be left outside and inevitably issues a `undefined control sequence`.

So the trick here is to define a *sudo* version of getthisrow which

- try to get the element by `\edef\tempa{\thisrow{houses}}`
- if it fails, try `\getthisrow{houses}{}` (Notice the empty argument)

  - `\pgfplotstablegetelem` will store the element to `\pgfplotsretval`
  - let `tempa` be `\pgfplotsretval`

## Full working code

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{fulltable.dat}
houses  instance    value
20      1           8919
20      2           8965
20      3           8901
20      4           8816
20      5           8875
20      6           9027
20      7           8915
20      8           8907
20      9           8832
20      10          8934
200     1           84714
200     3           85630
200     4           84748
200     5           84565
200     6           85109
200     7           84588
200     8           84638
200     9           84673
200     10          85170
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\def\thisrowunavailableloadtabledirectly{thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly}
\def\sudogetthisrow#1#2{
    \edef#2{\thisrow{#1}}
    \ifx#2\thisrowunavailableloadtabledirectly % if \thisrow fails to get the element
                            % then #2 is thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directlye
                            % we have a backup
        \getthisrow{#1}{}
        \let#2=\pgfplotsretval
    \fi
}

\pgfplotsset{
    discard if not/.style 2 args={
        x filter/.code={
            \sudogetthisrow{#1}\tempa
            \edef\tempb{#2}
            \ifnum\tempa=\tempb
            \else
                \def\pgfmathresult{inf}
            \fi
            \message{^^J\tempa,\tempb,\pgfmathresult^^J}
        }
    }
}

\pgfplotstableread{fulltable.dat}\fulltable

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[
      title={{\bfseries Plot for 20 houses instances}},
      xlabel={Instance},
      ylabel={Value}]
    \addplot+[only marks, discard if not={houses}{20}] table[x=instance, y=value]
      {fulltable.dat};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
  \begin{axis}[
      title={{\bfseries Plot for 20 houses instances}},
      xlabel={Instance},
      ylabel={Value}]
    \addplot+[only marks, discard if not={houses}{20}] table[x=instance, y=value]
      {\fulltable};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice solution, however I afraid it is usable only for few, very skilled `pgfplot` users. For wider use, features are very useful, the complexity use of this macros should be hidden from user :). Maybe in some kind `data-filter` library?