# Error interacting with `visualization depends on` with `values` and `pgfplotstable`

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

### Problem

When changing the values of the markers on a scatter plot using the `visualization depends on` key and when the data comes from a `\pgfplotstable` the marker printing is broken.

If I have the table data explicitly on the `addplot` it works (see example 3).  Similarly, if I have the data coming from a `pgfplotstable` and without the visualization handler, it also works (see example 1).

However, if I mix both, it just stops printing the markers (see example 2).

### Question

How can I make the `visualization depends on=value` and data coming from a `pgfplotstable` work together?

### Examples

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{a}{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{b}{\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{c}{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}

\pgfplotstableread{%
x y label
0.1  0.15 a
0.45 0.27 c
0.02 0.17 a
0.06 0.1  a
0.9  0.5  b
0.5  0.3  c
0.85 0.52 b
0.12 0.05 a
0.73 0.45 b
0.53 0.25 c
0.76 0.5  b
0.55 0.32 c
}{\tab}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
    scatter,
    only marks,
%    visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\label,
%    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\label},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y]{\tab};
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
    scatter,
    only marks,
    visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\label,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\label},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y]{\tab};
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
  scatter,
  only marks,
  visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\label,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\label},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y]{
    x y label
    0.1  0.15 a
    0.45 0.27 c
    0.02 0.17 a
    0.06 0.1  a
    0.9  0.5  b
    0.5  0.3  c
    0.85 0.52 b
    0.12 0.05 a
    0.73 0.45 b
    0.53 0.25 c
    0.76 0.5  b
    0.55 0.32 c
  };
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: examples of generation]

### More Context

I'm trying to create some columns from a table, and then trying to plot it.  Hence, my need to use a `pgfplotstable` as the source of the data.

I can change the size of the marker using `@pre marker code/.append code` handler.  However, the `@pre marker code/.append style` also gives error (not sure if that is related to this problem though).

So, in some sense, I can see that the `@pre marker code` is seeing the values created with the `visualization depends on` definition.  But for some particular reason it doesn't sees this one with non-numerical values.

Any ideas or hints why this may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there is an asymmetry in how data gets treated for explicit tables vs. tables that are stored in macros has been noted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356790/121799). I am using things discussed there to build a solution/workaround.  The data is read off and applied via

```
        scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/utils/exec=
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{label}\of{\tab}%\typeout{\mylabel,\pgfplotsretval}
    ,/tikz/mark=\pgfplotsretval},
```

That is, one can tell `pgfplots` explicitly how to get the data, and  not rely on `visualization depends on`.

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16} 
\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareplotmark{a}{\pgfuseplotmark{*}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{b}{\pgfuseplotmark{triangle*}}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{c}{\pgfuseplotmark{square*}}

\pgfplotstableread{%
x y label
0.1  0.15 a
0.45 0.27 c
0.02 0.17 a
0.06 0.1  a
0.9  0.5  b
0.5  0.3  c
0.85 0.52 b
0.12 0.05 a
0.73 0.45 b
0.53 0.25 c
0.76 0.5  b
0.55 0.32 c
}{\tab}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
    scatter,
    only marks,
%     visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\label,
%     scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\label},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y]{\tab};
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
    scatter,
    only marks,
    scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/utils/exec=
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\coordindex}{label}\of{\tab}%\typeout{\mylabel,\pgfplotsretval}
    ,/tikz/mark=\pgfplotsretval},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y] {\tab};
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[legend pos=south east]
  \addplot[%
  scatter,
  only marks,
  visualization depends on=value \thisrow{label}\as\mylabel,
  scatter/@pre marker code/.append style={/tikz/mark=\mylabel},
  ]
  table[x=x,y=y]{
    x y label
    0.1  0.15 a
    0.45 0.27 c
    0.02 0.17 a
    0.06 0.1  a
    0.9  0.5  b
    0.5  0.3  c
    0.85 0.52 b
    0.12 0.05 a
    0.73 0.45 b
    0.53 0.25 c
    0.76 0.5  b
    0.55 0.32 c
  };
  \legend{Class 1,Class 2,Class 3}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If needed, this can also be cast into a style.