# How to partition a pgfplotstable to use in multiple tikzpictures? (and duplicate a row)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, tikz-datavisualization

I'm trying to create multiple plots from one pgfplotstable (`\data` below). I can create the plots by manually editing the data (`\dataA` and `\dataB` below) but this is error-prone. Essentially, I need help:

- **partitioning** the table based on column `cat`
- **duplicating the last row** (except `xmin` is `xmax` from the previous row)
- **creating a loop** to create multiple `tikzpicture`s [*this I can probably figure out myself!*]

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.3   1   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.6   1   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.7   1   no
0.5    0    1  yes  0.4   2   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.5   2   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.9   2   no
}\data

\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.3   1   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.6   1   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.7   1   no
2.5    3    3  yes  0.7   1   no
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.4   2   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.5   2   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.9   2   no
2.5    3    3  yes  0.9   2   no
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5]
    \addplot[black, ybar interval] table[x=xmin,y=y] {\dataA}\closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5]
    \addplot[black, ybar interval] table[x=xmin,y=y] {\dataB}\closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Regarding **partitioning** the data, I have been able to print the partitioned table, but then how can I use it as input for `\addplot`?

```
\newcommand{\filtertable}[2]{
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  columns/par1/.style={string type},
  columns/par2/.style={string type},
  row predicate/.code={%
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{##1}{cat}\of{#1}
  \ifnum\pgfplotsretval=#2\relax
  \else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}
]{#1}
}

\filtertable{\data}{1}
\filtertable{\data}{2}
```

Regarding **duplicating the last row**, the only relevant value in the last rows is `xmin`. According to the PGF manual with `ybar interval` *"The last y value will be ignored."* I have unsuccessfully tried to create the same plot without the additional row. Note the distance between `xmin` and `xmax` must not always equal 1.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to install a filter like

unbounded coords=discard,
        x filter/.expression={\thisrow{cat}==1 ? x : nan}

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.3   1   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.6   1   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.7   1   no
0.5    0    1  yes  0.4   2   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.5   2   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.9   2   no
}\data

\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.3   1   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.6   1   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.7   1   no
2.5    3    3  yes  0.7   1   no
}\dataA

\pgfplotstableread{
x   xmin xmax par1    y cat par2
0.5    0    1  yes  0.4   2   no
1.5    1    2  yes  0.5   2   no
2.5    2    3  yes  0.9   2   no
2.5    3    3  yes  0.9   2   no
}\dataB

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5]
    \addplot[black, ybar interval,unbounded coords=discard,
    x filter/.expression={\thisrow{cat}==1 ? x : nan}] table[x=xmin,y=y] {\data}\closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ybar, ymin=0, ymax=1, xmin=-0.5, xmax=3.5]
    \addplot[black, ybar interval,unbounded coords=discard,
    x filter/.expression={\thisrow{cat}==2 ? x : nan}] table[x=xmin,y=y] {\data}\closedcycle;
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't compile on my installation.

Comment: The error is `Unknown function thisrow_unavailable_load_table_directly`. Apparently, `\thisrow` needs to be followed with the actual data table and not the variable `\data`.

Comment: @FrankSeifert On my installation it does compile. And since you edited it, you are probably aware of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356790/121799). However, on my machine I do not need any of this.