# pgf scatter not assigning classes styles

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to generate a scatter plot using the `pgfplots` package. However, I'm having troubles with the `scatter/classes` and `scatter src`options. For some reason, LaTeX keeps sending me the following error:

> Package pgfplots Warning: scatter/classes: can't find class for

At the end, LaTeX generates the chart but it does not assign any style to the coordinates:
[image]

Here's a minimal example of my code:

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
   % -> 
   \pgfplotsset{compat = newest} 
   \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
c1  c2  c3
1   1   a
2   4   b
7   2   c
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
      scatter/classes = {
         a = {mark = *, draw = green},
         b = {mark = *, draw = blue},
         c = {mark = *, draw = red}
       }]
      \addplot[                 
         scatter,
         only marks,
         scatter src = explicit symbolic] 
      table[
         x = c1, 
         y = c2,
         meta = c3,
         col sep = space
      ]{data.dat};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Tip: Instead of linking to some file for download, you could add `\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\]{c1 c2 c3 \\ 0 0 a \\ 1 0 b \\ 2 0 c\\}\datatable` to the preamble, and use `\datatable` instead of `data.csv` in the `\addplot`. Makes the example self contained as well.  (You can also use actual linebreaks instead of ```\\```, but that doesn't work well in comments.)

Comment: I almost completely agree with @TorbjørnT. but would actually suggest to add the table via `filecontents`, the reason being [that preloading the table and plotting it from the file are not completely equivalent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/356790/194703). I will add this to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question to be self-contained with `filecontents`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to replace the spaces between `a` and `=`, and similarly for `b` and `c`. Otherwise the names of the classes will contain these spaces.

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
c1;c2;c3
1;1;a
2;4;b
7;2;c
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{tikz} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
   % -> 
   \pgfplotsset{compat = newest} 
   \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
      scatter/classes = {
         a={mark = *, draw = green},
         b={mark = *, draw = blue},
         c={mark = *, draw = red}
       }]
      \addplot[                 
         scatter,
         only marks,
         scatter src=explicit symbolic] 
      table[
         x = c1, 
         y = c2,
         meta = c3,
         col sep = semicolon
      ]{data.csv};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the marks have a (hardly visible) halo of the respective color, if you want them also filled in these colors, use

```
\documentclass[border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
c1;c2;c3
1;1;a
2;4;b
7;2;c
\end{filecontents*}


\usepackage{tikz} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf
\usepackage{pgfplots} % https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
   % -> 
   \pgfplotsset{compat = newest} 
   \usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
      scatter/classes = {
         a={mark = *, green},
         b={mark = *, blue},
         c={mark = *, red}
       }]
      \addplot[                 
         scatter,
         only marks,
         scatter src=explicit symbolic] 
      table[
         x = c1, 
         y = c2,
         meta = c3,
         col sep = semicolon
      ]{data.csv};
   \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know that aspect of the scatter/classes names.